# python xpath loop through paragraphs and grab <strong>

Tags: python, loops, xpath

I have a series of paragraphs I'm trying to parse using xpath. The html is formatted like this:

```
<div id="content_third">
 <h3>Title1</h3>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  John Q Public <br>
  Susie B Private 
 <p>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  Anna C Public <br>
  Bob J Private 
 <p>
 <h3>Title1</h3>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  John Q Public <br>
  Susie B Private 
 <p>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  Anna C Public <br>
  Bob J Private 
 <p>
</div>
```

I'm setting up an initial loop like this:

```
titles = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_third"]/h3')
for num in range(len(titles):
```

Then an inner loop:

```
district_races = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_third"]/p[count(preceding-sibling::h3)={0}]'.format(num))
for index in range(len(district_races)):
```

Each loop, I want to select just the "District" within that `strong`. I've tried this, which spits out empty arrays except for one that's filled with all the Districts:

```
zone = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_third"]/p[count(preceding-sibling::h3)={0}/strong[{1}]/text()'.format(num, index))
```

Gotta love those unformatted state election webpages.

Comment: What module are you using? Please include any `import` lines. Also, only the word *District* is contained with `<strong>` tags. Please show desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I presume  each *District* is a placeholder for some actual name so to get  each District is a lot simpler than what you are trying to do, just extract the *text* from each *strong* inside each *p*:

```
h = """<div id="content_third">
 <h3>Title1</h3>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  John Q Public <br>
  Susie B Private
 <p>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  Anna C Public <br>
  Bob J Private
 <p>
 <h3>Title1</h3>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  John Q Public <br>
  Susie B Private
 <p>
 <p>
  <strong>District</strong>
  Anna C Public <br>
  Bob J Private
 <p>
</div>"""

from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(h)

print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="content_third"]/p/strong/text()'))
```